# R: creating a new vector based on condition of another vector

Tags: r, vector, vectorization

I have this vector:

```
x1<-c(1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4)
```

I want to create another vector of the same length that has "A" where any element in x1 is <3 and "B" otherwise.

The resulting vector would be:

```
c("A","A","A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B")
```

Comment: I simplified my question from my real problem which isn't solved with ifelse. I have a dataframe df which has one column df$a with numbers 1:20 and I want to add another column df$b that has "A" where df$a<3 and "B" otherwise. When I run the following I get an error: if (df$a<=3)
{df$b="A"
} else {df$b="B"}  -- The error I get is "In if (df$a <= 3) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used"

Comment: I think I have to use apply or sapply for my problem... Anyway thanks for your help.

Comment: @locket You get the error because you use `if` instead of `ifelse`.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative will be:

```
c("B", "A")[1 + (x1 < 3)]
# [1] "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B"
```

Benchmark

```
x1 <- c(1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4)

bench::mark("zheyuan-li" = ifelse(x1 < 3, "A", "B")
          , "Quinten" = c("B","A")[1 + (x1 %in% c(1,2))]
          , "GKi" = c("B", "A")[1 + (x1 < 3)]
            )
#  expression      min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc
#  <bch:expr> <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>
#1 zheyuan-li   5.86µs   8.13µs    92914.      600B     9.29  9999     1
#2 Quinten      1.38µs   1.87µs   474289.      600B    47.4   9999     1
#3 GKi        640.87ns    851ns  1099866.      400B     0    10000     0
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option:

```
c("B","A")[1 + (x1 %in% c(1,2))]
```

Output:

```
 [1] "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B"
```